# Is iteration an efficient algorithm in this case?

Tags: matlab, algorithms, numerical-analysis, ode

My task in numerical analysis is

> We are interested in finding values of β0 for which z(x) = 2500. Use
>   an efficient algorithm to determine the rays which pass through the
>   receiver.

Now I'm just looping through and printing and plotting it and seeing from inspection that the values between 8 and 9 and between -8 and -9 are candidates:

```
x=0:1:6076*25;
hold on

for w = -10:14

[X,Z] = ode45(@(t,Z) sys(t,Z,w),x,[2000 tand(7.8)]);

w
Z(end,[1,end])


plot(X,Z(:,1),'r')  %Z(:,1) is z(x) and Z(:,2) is z'(x).

end

hold off
```

Can it be done more efficient? β0 is the angle of the source of the sound and z(x) is the depth of the sound. My system is:

```
function dZ=sys(t,Z,w)

% inline function for c(z)
c=@(z)4800 - 20.2090 + (17.3368)*z/1000+ (272.9057)*exp(-z*0.7528/1000); 
% inline function for c'(z)

dc=@(z) 17.3368/1000 - (272.9057)*(0.7528/1000)*exp(-z*0.7528/1000); 
q=c(2000);
dZ=zeros(2,1);    % a column vector
dZ(1)=Z(2);
dZ(2)=-(q/cosd(w))^2* dc(Z(1))/c(Z(1))^3; 
end
```

Comment: What are $\beta0$ and $z$? I suspect without more detail, this question will get closed.

Comment: @BillBarth I updated the question with more detail. It's the same problem as in my previous questions. We consider the problem solved but I'm looking to understand it better and learn matlab.

Comment: We can't be expected guess which your questions to look back at. Each question on a SE site should be more or less self-contained. If you'd like to link to a question that explains the context, you should do that. All that being said, your printing/plotting technique is not an "efficient algorithm" in the sense that almost any assignment wants. You need to write a program that discovers the $\beta0$ values itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have these two things in mind which can help you.

1) Since I see that you are using ode45 i.e. runge kutta method, you probably can use adaptive runge kutta methods if you want to make your algorithm more efficient. This might remove the restriction of using every β value between your specified interval. You can find a video here which I saw quite sometime ago: http://nptel.ac.in/courses/122106033/33

2) And since you want to have a β for which z equals 2500. You can use additional array,say Y to store the value you get for that value of β. And having one more array, say A such that A=|z-Y| i.e. the difference between the z for current β value and z that is required. The minimum element of this array corresponds to the β you are looking for. You can look about this at: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html?refresh=true This removes the *inspection* aspect from your side and the program itself will tell which β is most suitable.

Hope it helps!